# How to implement "Endless Task" in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm new in Swift and I don't have much experience of it. And the thing is,  I'm having an issue of high CPU usage (over 100% cpu usage in Xcode Debug session) when I add following codes.

To implement endless working thread, I used GCD (most recommended way in many articles) including while-loop structure.

```swift
private let engineQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "engine queue", qos: .userInitiated)

public func startEngine() {
        engineQueue.async {
            while true {
                if (self.captureManager.isSessionRunning) {
                    guard let frame = self.captureManager.frameQueue.popFrame(),
                        let buf = frame.getYPlanar() else {
                            continue
                    }

                    // process a frame
                    self.engine.processNewFrame(buf: buf, width: Int32(frame.cols!), height: Int32(frame.rows!))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I noticed that this is a terrible practice (high CPU usage), and there must be a way better than this.

So questions are

1. Do I have to use GCD rather than Thread in this case?
2. What is the best way to work for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Either threads or queues should work but, rather than sitting in a tight loop, you should probably have this logic wait until something (`captureManager`?) wakes it and tells it there's work to do.  Maybe look at how semaphores work.

Comment: Endless loops that poll are a bad idea. Refactor your code to respond to an event so no CPU is used while waiting.

Comment: Have tried using timers? You start a timer that lives in a RunLoop and execute a function every time interval you set

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio That's just another form of polling.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I know but he asked for some kind of that actually.